# Dynamic src ------ js >>> to html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an audio file that I can play from this path.

/posts/THEFORCE.WAV

```
       <audio controls="controls" id="audio_player">
          <source src="/posts/THEFORCE.WAV" type="audio/ogg" />
          <source src="/posts/THEFORCE.WAV" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
```

I'm able to take input from a user 
and save the path to a server through index.js

```
const {song} = req.files

song: `/posts/${song.name}`

Output =  song: '/posts/THEFORCE.WAV' //This is not code just showing that song is a string
```

Question is....

How do I make html src"path" dynamic to the js const song

Answer (score 0):

You can select the source elements and replace their src value with your song

```js
const song = '/posts/NEW.wav'; // replace this with your dynamic fetched song
const sourceElems = document.querySelectorAll('#audio_player > source');

[...sourceElems].forEach(source => {
  source.src = song
  console.log('replaced source src:', source.src);
});
```

```html
<audio controls="controls" id="audio_player">
    <source src="/posts/THEFORCE.WAV" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="/posts/THEFORCE.WAV" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but after some experimenting I found using mustache brackets did the trick

Answer (score 0):

const post = mongoose.model('UploadSchema', UploadSchema)

```
   <audio controls="controls" id="audio_player">
      <source src="{{post.song}}" type="audio/ogg" />
      <source src="{{post.song}}" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
```